# Uploading Custom Label From IDE

Tags: metadata, customlabel

I was trying to add Custom Label to my SFDC sandbox, I am adding:

```
<labels>
    <fullName>Test</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <shortDescription>Test</shortDescription>
    <value>test</value>
</labels>
```

to CustomLabels.labels file, then deploy it. The problem is that I can't see that label created when I look for that in sandbox through setup, but when I retrieve labels again, I can see my label in file. Are there any additional steps that I need to take to get those labels shown in sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue working in VS Code, deploying to a sandbox with SFDX. However, I found I'm able to add labels and deploy to my sandbox by editing the file CustomLabels.labels-meta.xml (not CustomLabels.labels as you might expect).